# Is it possible in RMarkdown to print() in two columns?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm working in RMarkdown. I've got a lengthy df. I've used `subset()` to fetch a two column subset of the df. I need to print the entire subset in my report. I use `print(df)`. Is it possible to make the subset print in two side-by-side columns (thus reducing the *length* of the `print(df)` output?

Comment: Have you tried using `kbl` or `kable` functions in order to display your data-frame ?
This allows you to display your data-frame into a report table.
You could then play on text size or even table margin size.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Ah, I was unaware of `kbl`. Thank you, @Yacine Hajji!